# Proof of Satisfiability

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I'm learning about the satisfiability of consistent sets and I'm having trouble approaching an exercise.

Let $S := \{R\}$ with unary $R$ and let $\phi := \{\exists x\,Rx\} \cup\{\neg Ry \mid y\text{ is a variable}\}$

Show that $\phi$ is satisfiable and therefore consistent.

I'm not really sure how to approach this proof. Is there a proper procedure as to proving satisfiability of a set of sentences?

Comment: What is $S$? You've defined it in terms of an undefined term, and then a circularity "$R$ with unary $R$". Also, for $\phi$ did you mean $\{\exists x R x\} \cup \{\neg Ry \ | \ y\text{ is a variable }\}$, this may seem overly pedantic, but, $\phi$ usually represents a formula, not a set of formulas.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't have proper syntax for the latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I am lazy, I tend to not define "satisfiability" for formulas, only for sentences. This means I get to ignore free variables, and not consider what they represent.

Anyway, you can prove satisfiability directly: By exhibiting a model, (augmented with an interpretation for the variables). We need an object in the extension of $R$ to satisfy the first sentence, and, we need some number of objects not in the extension of $R$ to satisfy the formulas, so our model $\mathcal{M}$ should have at least two objects $\{0,1\}$, lets try $R^{\mathcal{M}} = \{0\}$. Now I need an intepretation of the variables, as I don't want them to be in the extension of $R$, map each variable to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty bad with this material, but I thought models were synonymous to interpretations. Also, how do you go about determining objects for which we can satisfy $\{\exists xRx\} \cup \{\neg Ry\}$? Is it just arbitrary?

Comment: It is arbitrary. A collection of sentences is satisfiable if there is some interpretation of the symbols that satisfies all the sentences. So, I just picked one.

Comment: I just want to ask a few more questions to make sure I have this straight. We need two objects in our model because we have two terms x and y? Now we choose arbitrary $R^M = \{0\}$ which means unary R holds for 0 (which satisfies $\exists xRx$). Finally, we map each variable to 1 which satisfies(satisfies $\neg Ry$?

Comment: You are close. We actually have infinitely many things saying $\neg R y, \neg R z, \ldots$ but the point is, that the variables $y,z,\ldots$ are unbound, and, aren't required to refer to different things. So, the "infinite part" of $\phi$ actually only requires that there is at least one object that doesn't have property $R$. The sentence $\exists x Rx$ requires that there is an object with property $R$. So, I need at least two, one in the extension of $R$ and one not in the extension of $R$. I just picked the simplest example satisfying that condition.

Comment: Also, it is probably worth noting that the formula $\neg R x$ appears in the "infinite part" yet this doesn't contradict $\exists x Rx$ because $x$ is bound in the second occurrence.

Comment: And because R is not specifically defined we can choose arbitrarily(and simply) $R^M = \{0\}$?

Comment: $R$ is never "defined" by the formulas, they just specify some properties it is supposed to satisfy. So, you get to choose $R$ arbitrarily, as long as it does indeed satisfy those properties.